# Magento 2 REST API paypal payment

Tags: api, paypal, rest-api, paypal-payments-pro

I'm developing a Magento client which depends totally on REST API. Regarding payment, this is from document:

> POST /V1/carts/mine/payment-information
>
> Set payment information and place order for a specified cart.

In admin, I configured as Paypal Payments Pro and was able to place an order using native storefront and test credit card number 4111... and see those (2) transactions in Paypal Manager. However when place an order with above endpoint method "payflowpro", it throws an error, and very likely that it doesn't do any credit card processing.

My question is does that endpoint do everything including processing CC and we just need to call that endpoint. Or we have to call Paypal SDK/API to process CC and that endpoint is just for update cart/order information?

Appreciate

Khoi

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach to validate payment because this is well suited to our requirement.

[validate-payment-paypal-magento-rest-api](http://www.ipragmatech.com/validate-payment-paypal-magento-rest-api/)